# No Input File Specified after Applying Patch

Tags: patches

I just installed a couple critical patches and followed the instructions here. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

After I ran the following command

```
chown -R root .
```

My site not says 'No input file specified.'

I tried reverting the patches and that didn't do anything.

Any Ideas? Do i need to reset the file permissions?

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 mage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the owner of your files to the root user. Your apache/www-data seems not to be able do read these files, that's why adapting your file permissions to 644 and 755 solved the issue.

You should change the file owner + group back to your web-server user (might be `www-data` and/or `apache` or something specific, ask your hosting provider if not sure). You should not run your webshop-files as root.

Answer (score 0):

These two commands fixed it.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```